# Measuring oscillator stability vs temperature

Tags: oscillator, frequency, clock, temperature, stability

How do people measure frequency stability vs temperature? Is it by having the data of frequency vs temperature and then try to fit the curve and finding the temperature coefficient or by finding ((d(frequency)/d(temperature))/frequency@25)*10^6?

I need to know how people measure frequency stability like in [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6463790) and many others.

Comment: Where does that 10⁶ factor come from?

Comment: i want to measure it in ppm/deg